# Context Free Grammar BNF

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, bnf, ebnf, ambiguous-grammar

need help with a non-extended BNF grammar:

```
Σ = {a,b,c}

L = {ω ɛ Σ^* | such that all a's (if any) comes before all c's(if any)}
```

For example, the strings aba, cbc, and abacbc are in the language, but string abcabc is not.

This is what i have so far (is it correct ? please correct me if i am wrong):

s->asbsc|bsasc|ascsb|ɛ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment says you want equal numbers of a and c, so start with the simple grammar that does that:

```
S -> aSc | ε
```

and add in any number of b's before/after/between those:

```
S -> BaScB | B
B -> Bb | ε
```

note that the above is not ambiguous (it's even LR(1)).

If you want to allow a different number of a's and c's, you can use the same approach to avoid ambiguity.  Start with just the a's and c's:

```
S -> AC
A -> Aa | ε
C -> Cc | ε
```

and add in b's at the beginning and after each other character:

```
S -> BAC
A -> AaB | ε
C -> CcB | ε
B -> Bb | ε
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the number of `a's` and `c's` need to be the same?  If, not then you are missing those cases where they differ, such as: `aac`.  I think something like this should work:

```
S -> AC
A -> aA | bA | ε
C -> bC | cC | ε
```

The `A` production is used for deriving a sequence of characters that are not a `c` and the `C` production is used for deriving a sequence of characters that are not an `a`.